# How can I tell if Windows thinks a HDD is removable without a GUI?

Tags: hard-drive, command-line, hyper-v, removable

I need to determine if Windows thinks that my SATA hard drives are "removable" or not.  The problem is, its on a Hyper-V system, and I don't have access to the Disk Management GUI application.  diskpart does not have this information, and I'm not sure where to turn now.   How can I determine this via command line tools, or through PowerShell?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is very easy in PowerShell using the .NET Framework, I've just tested it on an external drive :)

```
PS C:\>$drive = New-Object system.io.driveinfo("F:")
PS C:\>$drive.DriveType
Removable
```

You can also use WMI:

```
C:\>wmic
wmic:root\cli>logicaldisk get caption,drivetype
Caption  DriveType
C:       3
D:       5
E:       5
F:       2
```

Where drive types are:

```
0 - Unknown 
1 - No Root Directory 
2 - Removable Disk 
3 - Local Disk 
4 - Network Drive 
5 - Compact Disk 
6 - RAM Disk
```

Comment: This looks promising.  I'll test it out after work.